# Detect Specific Frequency From Microphone Java

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to capture audio that is coming from microphone and i wanted to check the frequency of sound. If I get a frequency greater then let's say : 1316.8 then I will start recording for 1 minute.

I am struggling with converting byte Data to Frequency.

I have used `Javax.sound` to capture audio that is coming from microphone and I have done the recording part as well.

```
  AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, true);

    DataLine.Info targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

    try {
        TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
        targetLine.open(format);
        targetLine.start();

        SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
        sourceLine.open(format);
        sourceLine.start();

        int numBytesRead;
        byte[] targetData = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() / 5];
```

I expect the output to be like Frequency of every sound that is coming from microphone.

Comment: You should probably look into an fft (fast fourier transform) library to perform the analysis of the PCM data into constituent frequencies. It's challenging to write what you want from scratch. Steve Smith's book "The Scientists and Engineers Guide to Digital Signal Processing" is a free download that will explain the theory and show code that accomplishes this, written in BASIC.